# postgres which data type to use for storing no of days (may include half days)

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

Which data type should be used to store no of days in a month (not more than 31 and may include half days like 5, 5.5, 10, 25.5).
It is always gonna be a integer or a float. If it is a float then it is always gonna be .5.

Comment: What about an integer that stores the number of hours?

Answer (score 3):

You could actually just the `INTEGER` type here, except that the column would store the number of *half* days.  To find out how many total complete days there were, you would have to divide by two (which, according to your rules, would either yield a whole number, or a whole number with a fractional component of 0.5).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/domains.html) for that.

```
CREATE DOMAIN halfdays
              AS numeric(3, 1)
                 CHECK (value >= 1
                        AND value <= 31
                        AND (value * 10) % 5 = 0);
```